# Proper use of global vars in PHP - Adding to an array from a Function

Tags: php, arrays, scope

Context: Two functions processing xml data that needs to be combined into a single array.

I am processing from multiple feeds and combining it into a multilevel associative array, like so:

```
$processedData:
Array ( 
    [item1] => Array ( 
        [somedata] => tasty
        [moredata] => food
        [evenmore] => like pizza
    ) 
    [item2] => Array ( 
        [somedata] => less tasty
        [moredata] => food
        [evenmore] => like bread pudding
    )
```

Each function is operating on separate data, and each gives me some of the data I need; for example, `somedata` and `moredata` come from `function one`, while `evenmore` comes from `function two`.

```
function one ($xml) {
    $myPrice = new XMLReader(); //some happy XMLReader stuff that works
    $myPrice->xml($xml);
    $key = ''; 

    while ($myPrice->read()) {
        if ($myPrice->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) { //only opening tags.
            $tag = $myPrice->name;
            switch ($tag) {
                case 'TheKey':
                    $key = $myPrice->readInnerXML();
                    break;
                case 'HowGood':
                    $processedData[$key]['somedata'] = $myPrice->readInnerXML();
                    break;
                case 'TypeOfThing':
                    $processedData[$key]['moredata'] = $myPrice->readInnerXML();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Function two` is structurally similar, but processes different data. Both functions should ideally return their data into one array. This can be easily accomplished by declaring `global $processedData` near the top of each function. Combining the return values with `array_merge` and `+` will overwrite values with the same key, according to the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Note: unlike most other questions about globals, the issue is not the input values, but the output values.

The question [Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why) suggests clearly labeling global variables to solve the common issues with global variables, but pretty much every answer on stack overflow re:Global Vars in PHP says **"you can do this, but you probably shouldn't."**

### My Question

Is combining return values from multiple functions a good use of php globals? Is there a way to do this avoiding global variables?

Or, alternatively, what cases are a good use of php globals? When are global variables good to use?

Comment: But if have result with the same key, how could you avoid rewriting values even using global?

Comment: @sectus The key is the same, but the "subkeys" are different. Using globals it works properly, as if you had done `$processedData[$key]['somedata']`, `$processedData[$key]['moredata']`, and `$processedData[$key]['evenmore']`. Your answer also works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your variable as second argument using reference.

```
function one($xml, &$processedData){}
function two($xml, &$processedData){}
```

It helps you to avoid using global.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference

Comment: Yes, this works. I was not familiar with the `&` pass-by-reference feature.